Angular memory leak in mergeMap and concatMap chain
I need to upload a 1 TB folder to Blob Storage and have designed a parallel processing pipeline using mergeMap to process and upload file through a series of steps using concatMap. each step in concatMap return an Observable.
it's working and files are getting processed but.
Problem: Causing memory leak with each processed file. memory is not getting freed up and causing the browser to throw out of memory exception just for 1 GB of files processed
My implementation:
html file
<!--INPUT FILE START-->
    <label for="folderUploadInput" class="folder-input-label hero-background">
      <span>{{selectedRootFolder}}</span>
      <mat-icon>folder</mat-icon>
      <mat-spinner diameter="50" class="mt-1" *ngIf="inProcessFiles.length>0"></mat-spinner>
      <input id="folderUploadInput" class="hide-element" type="file"
             (change)="onFolderSelected($event)" webkitdirectory directory/>
    </label>
<!--INPUT FILE END--> 

ts component:
onFolderSelected(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const splitFolder = this.splitFolderStructure(event.target.files[0]);
      this.selectedRootFolder = 'Folder selected - ' + splitFolder[0] + ', Total files - ' + event.target.files.length;
      this.processArrayOfFiles(event.target.files);
    } else {
      this.selectedRootFolder = 'No files in selected folder'
    }
  }

  splitFolderStructure(file: File) {
    return file.webkitRelativePath.split('/');
  }

  processArrayOfFiles(fileList: File[]) {
    this.totalFiles = fileList.length;
    if (this.totalFiles > 0) {
      const fileListToProcess: FileUploadTracking[] = this.initFileList(fileList);
      const parallelProcessingOfFiles = 10
      // Entire design is a pipeline per file basis. each file goes through a series of steps.
      of(fileListToProcess).pipe(
        // take one element at a time
        mergeMap(fileUploadTrackingList => fileUploadTrackingList),
        // process
        mergeMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
          this.inProcessFiles.push(fileUploadTracking);
          return this.checkIfMediaIsAlreadyPresent(fileUploadTracking).pipe(
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 1. Check if file present and creating it if not present
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.MEDIA_CREATED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.createMediaUploadDetails(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 2. update state to media details created
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.MEDIA_CREATED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.updateStateToMediaCreated(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 3. Check if the patient record is found, else stop the pipeline
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.PATIENT_FOUND, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.checkPatientExistForFile(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 4. update to patient found state
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.PATIENT_FOUND, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.updateStateOfCurrentFileToPatientFound(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 5. create thumbnail all the time becuase thumbnail is not saved till file is uploaded,
              // if the file is already uploaded skip the step
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.FILE_UPLOADED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.createThumbNailOfFile(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 6. update thumbnail state, if the file is already uploaded skip the step
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.FILE_UPLOADED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.updateStateOfCurrentFileToThumbnailGenerated(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 7. upload file to blob
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.FILE_UPLOADED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.uploadFileUsingGenericFileHandlerService(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 8. update uploaded state
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.FILE_UPLOADED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.updateFileDetailsIdAndUpdateState(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap(fileUploadTracking => {
              // 9. Create media activity log entry
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.ACTIVITY_LOG_CREATED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.createANewMediaActivityLogEntry(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            // WTF why the hell is this returning any. doesn't make any sense
            concatMap(fileUploadTracking => {
              // 10. update activity log state
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.ACTIVITY_LOG_CREATED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.updateActivityLogIdState(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 11. Link media to patient media assoc
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.MEDIA_LINKED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.linkToPatientMediaAssoc(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            concatMap((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              // 12. Link media to patient media assoc
              if (this.checkIfStepComplete(STEPS_LIST.MEDIA_LINKED, fileUploadTracking)) {
                return of(fileUploadTracking);
              } else {
                return this.updateStateToPatientMediaAttached(fileUploadTracking);
              }
            }),
            catchError((fileUploadTracking: FileUploadTracking) => {
              console.error(`large-uploader.component:catchError:fileUploadTracking - `, fileUploadTracking);
              this.erroredFiles.push(fileUploadTracking);
              return this.updateStateOfMediaUploadDetails(fileUploadTracking, {isFailed: true}, fileUploadTracking.error.message, true);
            })
          )
        }, parallelProcessingOfFiles),
      ).subscribe({
        // weird error, had to forcefully put res:any even though its clearly res:FileUploadTracking
        next: (res: any) => {
          this.inProcessFiles = this.inProcessFiles.filter(item => item.mediaUploadDetails.OriginalFilePath !== res.mediaUploadDetails.OriginalFilePath);
          this.processedFiles++;
          this.overAllProcess = +(((this.processedFiles / this.totalFiles) * 100).toFixed(1));
          this.getTableData();
        },
        error: err => {
          console.error("large-uploader.component:processArrayOfFiles:error:  err ", err);
          this.insightService.logException(err, 'large-uploader.component', 'error ', '306', SeverityLevel.Error);
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log(`large-uploader.component:complete:processArrayOfFiles:complete - completed`);
          this.callAPIMetadataOperation();
          this.snackBar.open('Upload complete', 'OK');
        }
      })
    }
  }


Found the issue, moved
const fileListToProcess: FileUploadTracking[] = this.initFileList(fileList);
was not freeing up after a file was processed. moved the initialization of files to class property this.fileList = [] where I can then splice the this.fileList soon after the file was processed.
